# SQLite query not executing on C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

The code doesn't produce an exception and seemingly runs fine. But after running it and checking the table i see that the row is not inserted. I use navicat for cheking and that's not the problem. I've double-checked the table name and field names which all correct. What's wrong?

```
try
{
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=path;Version=3;FailIfMissing=True");

    conn.Open();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO sales (cust_id, date, cost, price) VALUES ('0', '" + String.Format("{0:u}", DateTime.Now.Date).Split(' ')[0] + "', '" + cost.ToString() + "', '12')";
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn);

    conn.Close();
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    MessageBox.Show(err.Message.ToString());
}
```

Comment: because its never executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add:

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

on your code:

```
...
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also it is always better to use parameters on your query